# document.getElementById is not working while iframe is showing in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

HTML:

```
$scope.refreshSection = function ($event) {
            ajaxService.getData("/home/index", "")
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.section= data;
                });
        }
```

I have Iframe to add the items to the list. After item gets added I need to refresh this section dynamically from script.

SCRIPT:

```
function refresh(){
    //other stuffs 
    var sectionScope = angular.element(document.getElementById("items")).scope();
        sectionScope.refreshSection();
}
```

While this line executing I am getting `sectionScope` as undefined because `document.getElementById("items")` is null.

Why I am not getting the value ?

Comment: You cannot access Iframe's content from outside of iframe

Comment: The id "items" is not present in iframe. outside the frame only.

Comment: please share your html

Comment: In the code, you have used `Function`, isn't it suppose to be `function`? `JavaScript` is case sensitive :)

Comment: Sorry typo.. I have changed now.